# com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsf, managed-bean

I am trying to deploy a newspaper website. It works fine with the main page (list of articles) but when I click on one of them, to go to the article page, I get this Exception:

> oct 31, 2014 11:41:35 AM
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy
>   handleRenderException SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/noticia.xhtml]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.faces.context.UrlBuilder.addValuesToParameter(UrlBuilder.java:318)

I am using Maven and Tomcat 7.0.

Full Stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/QjZAYPLL

noticia.xhtml: http://pastebin.com/xGY7cmQw

FrontPageMB: http://pastebin.com/fBtnqphp

Pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/0EKp6FR2

Web.xml: http://pastebin.com/Eeymsm1f

Comment: Done, have a look ;)

Comment: Are you using latest Mojarra? There seems to be a [related error](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3355) which was fixed in 2.2.8.

Comment: From server log -> INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.8-02 ( 20140915-1602 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8-02@13678)

Comment: I am also getting this error from JPA: The currently selected library provider is invalid